# How to use read.csv to read only those lines that matche with some regular expression?

Tags: r, regex, csv

I want to read a large file using `read.csv` in `R`. Now one way to fetch lines matching with some pattern is to fetch all lines in a `data-frame` first and then to filter only required lines. The problem with this approach is that the file size is too large and all data may not fit in memory on some machines. So is there any way I can use `grep` or something similar along with `read.csv` to fetch only few lines that are of interest?

Comment: You could use `grep` (or `awk`) in the shell/terminal to filter out certain lines, send to a new file, then read that file into R.  Otherwise you can read the data in by chunks then filter the chunks

Comment: Thanks for your help @RichardScriven. I was looking if anything is available in `R` to do it using `read.csv` and `regex` or something similar.

Comment: You can use shell commands with `fread` from `data.table`. See e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22229109/r-data-table-fread-command-how-to-read-large-files-with-irregular-separators for an example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't use `read.table` and its derivatives for this purpose. You can, however, use `readLines` to read in data in chunks and apply your regular expression to each element, which corresponds to a line.

Another alternative would be to use a database like framework. [Package `sqldf`](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/sqldf/index.html) can read a csv file into a SQL data base. You can use an SQL query to read only desired lines.