# How to read when delimiter is space and missing values are blank?

Tags: r, data.table, delimiter, fread

I have a space delimited file and some columns are blank, so we end up having multiple spaces, and *fread* fails with error. But *read.table* works fine. See example:

```
library(data.table)
# R version 3.4.2 (2017-09-28)
# data.table_1.10.4-3

fread("A B C D
1 2  3
4 5 6 7", sep = " ", header = TRUE)
```

> ```
> Error in fread("A B C D\n1 2  3\n4 5 6 7") : 
>   Expected sep (' ') but new line, EOF (or other non printing character) ends field 2 when detecting types from point 0: 1 2  3
> ```

```
read.table(text ="A B C D
1 2  3
4 5 6 7", sep = " ", header = TRUE)
#   A B  C D
# 1 1 2 NA 3
# 2 4 5  6 7
```

How do we read using *fread*, I tried setting `sep = " "` and `na.string = ""`, didn't help.

Answer (score 4):

In *fread* function, by default `strip.white` is set to `TRUE`, meaning leading trailing spaces are removed. That is useful to read files with [fixed width](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32620679) or with [irregular number of spaces](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32597914/680068) as separator.

Whereas in *read.table* `strip.white` by default is set to `FALSE`.

```
fread("A B C D
1 2  3
4 5 6 7", sep = " ", header = TRUE, strip.white = FALSE)
#    A B  C D
# 1: 1 2 NA 3
# 2: 4 5  6 7
```

---

**Note:** Providing self-answer as I couldn't find relevant post, also this tripped me over [once](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/37609292#37609292) and [twice](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/40771970#40771970).

---

**Edit:** This doesn't work anymore for data.table_1.12.2, [related GitHub Issue](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/3658).

Comment: One minute from question to self-answer?

Comment: @snoram It is [encouraged](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer), also, mainly, I am posting for future reference for myself, as I will likely again forget :)

Comment: Nice. +1 then. I guess everyone using `fread()` should take note.

Comment: I ran into a similar problem with the main difference being that in some lines the last column was missing.  In addition to your solution `fill = TRUE` was also needed.

Comment: I posted the same question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65646742/r-data-table-fwrite-to-fread-space-delimiter-and-empties before finding yours here.  I added a solution there using sed.

Comment: @MarkE. Thanks for linking the posts. Yes, workarounds are possible, but I think this is an issue, and has to be fixed within data.table. I will update my answer when the GitHub issue gets closed/resolved.